# Closing/killing applications in Linux Mint (Cinnamon)

Tags: linux-mint, cinnamon, desktop-environment

I recently switched to mint (Cinnamon 4.4.8) and having hard time closing applications. I had ubuntu 20.04 and installed cinnamon DE over it.

When I try to close some applications it gets closed but does not go away from the bottom menu bar. Menu bar shows the application as open but when you click on it, neither the existing (closed but showing) window opens nor a new window opens. I have to right-click and start a new window of the application. Moreover, right-clicking and closing all instances of application do not work either. Some of these closed applications do not show up in the running processes.

Attached is a screenshot of the menu bar

[image]

Comment: Could it be related to [that issue](https://github.com/linuxmint/cinnamon/issues/8856) ? "_Grouped Window List - Zombies stay alive after being closed #8856_"

Comment: yes! Thanks! This is indeed the bug

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As pointed by @user4089, this is a bug related to "Grouped Window List" https://github.com/linuxmint/cinnamon/issues/8856

To fix it, I disabled Grouped Window List in the applet and started using another window list applet. I am using `CobiWindowList` but I think any other should also work fine.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't mind using a terminal, then you can use the `pkill` command like this:
`pkill [process name]`, e.g. `pkill chrome`.

Comment: This kills the process but doesnot make it go away from the menu bar

Answer (score 0):

you can do `killall process-name` 
or just type `xkill` the choose the windows that you want close

Comment: I can't choose the window as window is gone. It just stays in the menu bar

Comment: if you type `xkill` you'll see an X replaces the mouse cursor just right click in the window then it will be closed